# How do I prevent text from moving with the image and vise versa?

Tags: html, css

I am new to coding and currently developing my first website so bear with me. Every time I try to upsize the image I want in the center of the page, the title text moves with the image as if the title text (.wrd-box) is being pushed by the image when the image (`.image2`) upsizes. Ive tried to style the title text (`WELCOME TO THE OFFICIAL VCU GYM CLUB HOMEPAGE`) with fixed positioning and that doesn't seem to work. I'm honestly not sure what else to try. Here's what I have below. Again, I'm new to this so I'll take all the advice/suggestions I can get.

```css
.wrd-box {
  width: 90%;
  color: #FFD700;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 610px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.trademark {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1px;
  color: gray;
}

.image2 img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  top: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <nav>
    <div class="image1">
      <a href="club.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg"></a>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="wrd-box">
    <h1>WELCOME TO THE OFFICIAL VCU GYM CLUB HOMEPAGE</h1>
    <div class="image2">
      <a href="club.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200/FF0000" alt="gym picture" width="300" height="300"></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi @calcoder7 and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please include a minimum reproducible example as a Stackoverflow snippet. You can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: note, that the code you provided has at least 1 missing closing tag (within the nav element).  Also, `position: relative` on a replaced element that can not have any child elements! Please use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) to check if your markup is valid before asking!

Comment: You need to help us understand both *what is happening* and *what you want to happen*. Perhaps draw some sketches on a bit of paper and take photos of them to add to your question to illustrate your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to lie in the css file.
Using the "position: relative;" property affects how other elements around it are positioned.

Instead, you can try seperating the .image2 class into ".image2" and a ".image2 img" tag. This can help you scale without affecting the other elements in the page

```
.image2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.image2 img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```